# Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on null

Tags: php, oop, ioc-container

I am using League Container package as DI in my project.

```
class App extends Container {};
```

above code working fine.but problem trigger whenever in use constructor in my app class.
class App extends Container

```
{  
   public __construct(){};
}
```

it shows like-
Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on null

i want to know what does it causes in oop prgramming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of reasons it wouldn't work:

- `public __construct(){};` is not the correct way to define a class construct.

If that's just a typo the actual error you would be getting is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDefinition() on a non-object
>   in ...

This is because if you extend a class which has a construct, then you must call the parent construct or it will discard it. ([which it does](https://github.com/thephpleague/container/blob/master/src/Container.php#L60)).

So putting them 2 points together here is a working example:

```
<?php
// require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Container\Container;

class App extends Container {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Foo {

}

$container = new App;

// add foo to the container
$container->add('foo', 'Foo');

// retrieve foo from the container
$service = $container->get('foo');

var_dump($service instanceof Foo); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "function" after "public".